# How do I properly install GRUB on a RAID 0 created with mdadm?

Tags: grub2, raid, mdadm

How do I properly install GRUB on a mdadm RAID 0? I try to install grub and it doesnt properly install, like /etc/default/grub is missing.

Comment: BIOS or UEFI? Ubuntu release/version? Hardware specifications?

Comment: I recommend to have a regular ext2 `/boot` partition. Everything else can be in a raid. Even if it might be possible, it will hard to setup a grub bootstrap with native raid drivers. After loading initramfs from the `/boot` partition, the raid will be setup properly. If there isn't a simple boot partition, you also will have more trouble to start from a recovery boot sector if your boot sector cannot be started from BIOS for some reason.

Comment: So just create a small (50-100 MB) `ext2` partition, set a mount point `/boot` in `/etc/fstab` and mount. Remember to run `update-grub` after any change on the boot system.